# Указан @Qualifier для поля в коде на bean с не-null значением, но в ходе работы программы в контейнере объектов поле имеет значение null

Tags: java, spring, required

Конфигурация:

```
<bean class = "java.lang.String">
    <qualifier value = "db_name"/>
    <constructor-arg value = "db_name_using_bean_with_qualifier"/>
</bean>
<bean id = "any_project" class="ru.miron.Annotations.Database"/>
```

Класс `Database`:

```
public class Database {
    @Autowired(required = true) // true on_default
    @Qualifier("db_name") // name of bean to search
    private String name;

    ...

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("db name: " + name);
    }

}
```

Исполняемый код:

```
Database dbFromConfigUsingQualifiers = context.getBean("any_project", Database.class);
dbFromConfigUsingQualifiers.print();
```

Ожидаемый вывод:

> db name: db_name_using_bean_with_qualifier

На деле:

> db name: null

Ошибки не было. Это означает, что оно нашло по `qualifier'у` `bean`. Но как так получилось, что оно нашло `bean`, имеющий значение, и подставило `null` на его место - ума не приложу

Comment: Ты знал, что ссылочные типы, если они не инициализированы, по умолчанию будут иметь значение null?

Comment: @NarasuOo да, знал. Spring должен сам инициализировать переменную значением bean'а с qualifier'ом db_name.

Comment: Autowired не для того придумали, чтобы строки инжектить. Возможно, в этой ситуации больше подходит аннотация `@Value`

Comment: @NarasuOo его придумали, чтобы инжектить bean'ы. Строка это объект - значит может быть bean'ом, разве не так?

Comment: Попробую........

Comment: @NarasuOo с произвольными объектами тоже почему-то не работает

Comment: По поводу DI, одно из его главных преимуществ - это слабая связанность. Для этого отлично подходит программирование через интерфейсы, поэтому обычно именно их и инжектят. Да, ты можешь инжектить строку как бин, но никакой выгоды ты от этого не получишь. Насчет "с произвольными объектами тоже почему-то не работает" я не совсем понял, ты попробовал добавить `@Value`?

Comment: @NarasuOo Я забыл указать `<context:annotation-config/>` в `.xml`. Как оно работало с `required = true` - непонятно, должно было крашиться по идее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Забыл "подключить" аннотации. Делается это с помощью добавления следующих строк в `<bean сюда>`:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd"
```

И в само тело `bean`:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```